# Insufficient resources for SoftLayer VLAN issue

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, vlan

When I attempted to create an autoscale group with one VM, Softlayer complained about the message below.

There are insufficient resources behind router bcr02.wdc01 to fulfill the request for the following guests: sltest-8f0e

I know that it most likely caused by me having selected a VLAN with insufficient portal IP address. As I can see this VLAN has two portable subnets, each one having one unused portable IP address. So theoretically it should be able to allow me to create one VM within this VLAN. Could you explain why I get this error message? Which parameter should I check in order to know if this VLAN has unallocated IP addresses for creating an autoscale group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servers can only provisioned over **PRIMARY or ADDITIONAL_PRIMARY subnets**, in case that you select a VLAN which doesn't have a PRIMARY with available slots, another subnet of this kind (PRIMARY) will be provisioned automatically in the VLAN.

The exception means that there are no places to put a new instance behind the router, there is just no space. So you need to define another vlan located in other pod. You can try with SAN or LOCAL (if you would like to get more info about this, submit a ticket for it)

To check vlans, you can use the following rest request (it will provide vlans for a specific datacenter):

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans?objectFilter={"networkVlans":{"primaryRouter":{"datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"seo01"}}},"networkSpace":{"operation":"PRIVATE"}}}

Method: Get
```

**Replace**: $user, $apiKey, seo01 (datacenter's name), PRIVATE (options: PRIVATE or PUBLIC).

Comment: Thanks. This information is very useful. The request you gave above only lists the VLANs with their primary subnets in seo01, but it doesn't suggest if there is sufficient `place` (the concept you mentioned above) to accept the request behind one specific VLAN. So this is exactly what I need since I want my toolings to be aware of the available places before allowing people to place the order.

Comment: Unfortunately, it depends from the resources available from each pod, there is not way to check this from customer's side (This exception is shown rarely), we always recommend to chose another datacenter when this happens(Also you can try with a different pod).  I recommend to submit a ticket to Sales, if you would like to get certain information about which datacenter would not have this kind of issues (Perhaps in the last datacenters like: osl01, seo01, wdc04, che01)

Comment: The request that I provided will only help to get vlans which you can use, as I said, it's not possible to get which pods have enough resources because the issue is rarely raised

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate that!!